# Как центрировать созданный див по горизонтали?

Tags: jquery

В скрипте создается div, потом в него пихается некоторое содержимое, которое меняет ширину div'a. Как после этого центрировать div по горизонтали?
Код CSS:

```
.popup_block{
    display: none; /*--по умолчанию скрыты--*/
    background: #eee;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 4px solid #ddd;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    z-index: 99999;
    /*--CSS3 Тени для Блока--*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    /*--CSS3 Закругленные углы--*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
    $('body').append('<div id="pht" class="popup_block"></div>');
```

Comment: Пользуйтесь инструментом Хрома (браузер): Инструмент разработчика (Ctrl+Shift+I), там будет легче увидеть что припывается к каждому классу, id и что нужно изменить.

Comment: div с id='pht' и class="popup_block"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@Sh4dow](/users/465/sh4dow)](/users/465/sh4dow) он в скрипте делает :)
для jquery так:

```
$("#myId").css('margin','auto');
```

На чистом JS:

```
document.getElementById("myId").style.margin = 'auto';
```

Но, обычно, лучше прописать стили прямо в css, т.е. тупо подключить css файл где написать;

```
#myId {
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: А разница, где он делает?) Итог-то одинаковый. Подозреваю, что у него `position: absolute` или ширина не указана, тогда хакать придется.

Comment: а не лучше просто убрать(если он есть конечно) `position:absolute`?<br>
А если ширина не задана - не проще задать? Зачем сразу хакать? ^^<br><br>
А разница большая - ковырять js код или css?

Comment: Это может быть модальное окно или алерт, тогда ни 1, ни 2 мы не сделаем. Ну и суть в установке стиля же? Его можно прописать в html, запилить в css или выставить скриптом, но тот же фаербаг все равно покажет `style="margin: 0px auto 0px auto;"` =)

Comment: position: absolute, без этого не работает.

Comment: просто уберите `position:absolute`, `float:left`, бред с `left` и просто напишите: `margin:auto;`<br><br>
Если же все равно не то - напишите что именно изменилось и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').append('<div id="pht" class="popup_block_outer"><div class="popup_block"></div></div>');
```

CSS:

```
.popup_block_outer { position: absolute; z-index: 9999; top: 50%; left: 50%; }
.popup_block { position: relative; float: left; /* ваши стили */ }
```

`float: left` - для того, чтобы див не растягивался на всю доступную область.

К сожалению, в jquery не шарю, поэтому на чистеньком. После заполнения текстом делать такое:

```
var pht = document.getElementById('pht').getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
pht.style.marginLeft = '-'+Math.round(pht.offsetWidth * 0.5)+'px';
pht.style.marginTop = '-'+Math.round(pht.offsetHeight * 0.5)+'px';
```

То есть, выставляем левый и верхний отступы в минус половину ширины и высоты соотв-но.

Comment: не работает

Comment: на ваш вопрос я могу ответить только так. По-хорошему дайте стили дива и код, которым див создается и заполняется.

Comment: обновил, пробуйте

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду пробовать. Но ошибка видимо не в css, а в самом скрипте создания/удаления div'a...

Comment: Лучше пользоваться не `Math.round(pht.offsetWidth * 0.5);` а `(pht.offsetWidth>>1)`

Comment: Вообще центровка абсолютного блока с неизвестной шириной - давняя проблема и только стилями она не решается, не считая иешное `expression`, что по сути тоже скрипт) Обычно люди сдаются и явно задают ширину, получается что-то типа "`width: 300px; margin-left: -150px;`". А вообще раз уж у вас jquery - взяли бы плагин, их море. Модальные окна, попапы, подсказки, алерты и тп.

Comment: @timka_s , это я потом бы еще объяснял про `<<1`, а вот за "px" спасибо)